# Using GoogleViewer for displaying documents in the Localhost

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver

I have uploaded a few slides on localhost and would like to use googleviewer to display them as it is difficult using php. Is there a library in php which i can possibly use??

Can anyone please tell me how can i use googleviewer to view the documents in my localhost?

Appreciate the help in advance:)
Regards 
Anjana

Comment: Its possible, you could use a form to upload the .pdfs to your localhost, but also upload them to an external site with cURL, use a database to hold the file names and locations and any other stuff then use a full page iframe to this address `http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Flabs.google.com%2Fpapers%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf&embedded=true` replacing the url_encoded url with the location of the hosted pdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/**
 * Retrieve public ip with PHP cURL
 */
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://whatismyip.org/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
$public_ip = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

//echo "my ip address is ".$public_ip;

/**
 * Let's say we have the slide located
 * at http://localhost/papers/bigtable-osdi06.ppt
 * The link to view it from google viewer will be
 */

 echo 'http://docs.google.com/viewer?url='.urlencode("http://$public_ip/papers/bigtable-osdi06.ppt");

?>
```

I retrieve the url with the cURL trick because there isn't a PHP method to let you know your     public ip and this way works both in windows or linux as long as http://whatismyip.org/ is up and running.

**Edit:**

Ofcource your web-server has to be accessible from the internet!

Comment: I tried running the script but it says not able to retrieve it or permission not there. Kindly suggest how to resolve this. My localhost is online only.

Comment: I suppose that your web-server isn't accessible via the internet and that's why google viewer can't load the document. If that's the case you have to configure your web server accordingly ,port forward the service and disable any firewall restrictions. To confirm that this is the problem try to reach your web-server from it's public ip address.

Comment: Ya my router is preventing the access. How can I configure it?

Comment: You have to port forward the service. Take a look here http://portforward.com/. I can't tell you exactly how to do that because every router has different interface but try to login to your router's web interface and there you will find an option about that by the name "NAT" or "virtual servers" or something like that. Then you'll have to enter the server's lan ip address and the port that you want to forward. However, by doing that have in mind that other people would be able to see the content of your web-server.